# Best practice for declaring views, models etc. in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've seen backbone views (or models, collections etc), declared like this

```
var SomeView = Backbone.View.extend({...
```

I've also seen them declared like this

```
window.SomeView = Backbone.View.extend({...
```

Could someone please explain the pros/cons in each case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really it does the same thing: http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/global_variable

However http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-constructor example goes with the first example and would be understood by a larger audience.

Answer (score 3):

Some people prefer to have only one global variable (important for libraries, not so much for normal pages) and use something like:

```
var MyApp = {
   Models: {},
   Collections: {},
   Views: {}
}
```

and then for each view:

```
MyApp.Views.SomeView = Backbone.View.extend({...
```